Using persistent homology to measure the "isotropy" of a graph
Suppose we have a random graph where the positions of the vertices are significant. How can I measure the isotropy of this graph? I may not be using the correct terminology, but essentially, I'm looking for a metric that can effectively differentiate between two specific types of graphs, given their sets of vertices and edges. For example,

I expect the graph on the left to be more isotropic, potentially characterized by a more uniform distribution of the angles of inclination of the edges. Any help with the precise mathematical terminology would be greatly appreciated.
Some thoughts: Initially, I considered using the adjacency matrix and vertex locations to evaluate the distribution of the angles of inclination. However, I'm curious if there's a more accurate method to quantify isotropy in this context.
Some further thoughts: I have recently come across the concept of persistent homology as a tool for computing network features with topological underpinnings. I was wondering if I could somehow apply this to this embedded graph to say a bit more than simply deducing the distribution of edge slopes. Any ideas?

The "angles of inclination of the edges" are a feature of the embedding of the graph in $\Bbb R^2$, not of the graph itself, i.e., a typical isomorphic graph will not have the same angles. If you're interested in a property that depends on a particular embedding of a graph, it would be clearer to ask for, e.g., the "'isotropy' of a graph embedding".

@TravisWillse Could persistent homology help characterise network features such as this "isotropy" on embedded graphs?
